# prevent a default action with IE8

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-8

I have a script that on ONKEYDOWN event (e.g. Alt+f) it disables the default action that is
to make browser to show its menu and make my custom action.

In IE8 `event.returnValue` does not do the job. I have also viewed that if I do
`alert(event.returnValue)` the value is 'undefined' ad it seems as that property there isn't
in the object but if I cycle the event object I found it.

Strange enough!

Maybe the browser access keys could not be disabled?

P.S.
With Firefox all works! (with `preventDefault()`)

Comment: I think this is one of those key combos (in IE) that you can't override.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not possible to override behavior of "Ctrl+KEY" shortcuts (in IE), you can still override access keys. Use plain simple HTML for that.

```
<a href="javascript:;" accesskey="f"></a>
```

Hope this helps.